# file move c# error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, ios, file

I have already searched and read all questions about this problem, but i did not get the solution yet. I tried to move an image to destination path. And this is my code:

```
   private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string TempDir = "";
       ParentFolder = ParentFolder.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
       for(int i=1 ;i<=ClusterNumber;i++)
       {
           TempDir=ParentFolder+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+i.ToString();
           bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(TempDir);
           if (!isExists)
               System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(TempDir);
           else
           {
               //DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Folder "+i.ToString() +" >already existed in parent folder, do you want to overwrite it ?", >"Confirmation",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
       {
           TempDir = ParentFolder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + listBox2.Items[i].ToString() + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+ Path.GetFileName(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
           System.IO.File.Move(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), TempDir); //The error is here
       }
   }
```

The error happened on the "System.IO.File.Move".
Data from debugging :

```
  TempDir = "C:\\Users\\Chun\\Desktop\\1\\Button.jpg";
  listBox1.Items[i] = "D:\\Revisi TA\\kumpulan gambar\\Button.jpg";
  ParentFolder = "C:\\Users\\Chun\\Desktop";
  listBox2.Items[i] = "1";
```

Comment: Is the file that you are trying to move assigned to some picture box?

Comment: @NoOne should not. maybe i should check it. if i assign it to null. is it okay ?

Comment: create a copy and then assign it to picture box. otherwise reference won't be removed.

Comment: Use Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out what process is locking the file. This may give you an clue on how to fix the problem.

Comment: I have try using pictureBox.Image.Dispose(). And the error message changed to "Object reference not set to instance of an object"

Comment: @NoOne Thanks, it solve my problem. So i will delete the files when the program closed